# onload slideDown of a div, slideUp the div on button click

Tags: jquery, html, css, slidedown, slideup

i am attempting onload slideDown. when the page is opened, the div is slideDown automatically after 2 seconds. the div consist of responsive image and a button called "z-indexed".
now what i need is to slideUp that same div. i am using the below code to do but not working for slideUp. when i click the z-indexed button nothing happens.

i'm beginner to jquery and i got really stuck. please help me with this, your effort will be appreciated, thanks.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>slideDown</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
           $("#mydiv").slideUp(1).delay(2000).slideDown('slow');
           $("#mybutton").click(function() {
               $("#mydiv").slideUp();      // i think here's the problem
           });
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        img{
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>here is some text , you will see an image and a button, after 2 seconds. when you click on the button the div will slideUp.</h2>
    <div id="mydiv">
        <button id="mybutton">z-indexed</button>
        <img src="php.jpg">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to put the click event inside the document ready too, you're declaring it before the element you're trying to bind to exists in the DOM.

Comment: @delinear thanks man the problem is solved, it starts working.

Answer (score 1):

There's two issues:

- You forgot the hash sign in your selector: `$('mybutton').click...`
- You're trying to attach the click handler to it before it exists

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mydiv").slideUp(1).delay(2000).slideDown('slow');
    $("#mybutton").click(function() {
        $("#mydiv").slideUp();      // i think here's the problem
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks man the problem is solved, it starts working.